# How to not make backbone.js use the save response as model attributes

Tags: backbone.js

So when I save a model on the backend, My api send back a response telling everything went fine and giving you some other pointers in json format

My problem is that backbone think I want to use that response as attributes of my model and automatically dump them in the model attributes..

I just saved it on the front-end and do not want to save the attributs again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the what `Backbone.Model.parse` is for.  By default, it is just a pass-through, so you don't need to call "super".

Let's say you only care about two properties that come back (id and foo) and you don't care about anything else:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    parse : function(resp, xhr) {
        return {
            id:  resp.id,
            foo: resp.foo
        };
    }

});
```

Note that I included "id" in my example.  It is really important that creates (POST) return an id property.  Without it, the Backbone model won't know how to update/delete in the future.  Even if it has a different name for id (like "objectId"), you should still set the id in this function.

Comment: Was the more accurate in what I needed to do, I did something in the line of   parse : function(resp, xhr) {
    if(resp.type && (resp.type =="create" || resp.type =="update")){
    
    }else{
     return resp;
    }
    },

Comment: I've just come across this. As of Backbone 1.0.0, if you pass `{parse: false}` as the second argument to the `save` method then the server response isn't treated as new attributes. See http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-61.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed that's the default behaviour, and if you want to change it, you have to overwrite some Backbone functions.

Looking at how `save` is implemented, you have two options - either overwrite `save` for your model, or overwrite `parse` to make it aware of the data you are sending.
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41

Or, you could give up sending the 'pointers' in the response, because an empty response means that the model does not change after save.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact issue you are encountering. Backbone is a pretty young framework with the additional fact that javascript is really dynamic. So the saying that there are a thousand ways to solve a problem applies really well here.

I think a more suitable way to go about this is to employ something called [Mixins](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#mixins). Here's what I did:

```
define([
   'underscore',
   'backbone',
   'jquery'
], function (_, Backbone, $) {

return {
    parse: function(response, xhr){
        var data = response;
        if(response.response && response.response.status != 0){
            return {};
        }
        if(response.response && response.response.data)
        {
            data = _.first(response.response.data);
            if(typeof data == 'undefined'){
                data={};
            }

        }
        if(_.isFunction(this.postParse)){
            return this.postParse.call(this, data);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
});
```

As you can see, I've overridden the Backbone.Model.parse prototype method and came up with my own that takes in a response. And parse the response according to my server's spec. In you case, you would implement whatever it takes to understand your server's response.

With the ground work out of the way, specifying a model is very easy:

```
var group = Backbone.Model.extend(
    _.extend({}, ModelMixin, {
        initialize:function () {
        }
    })
);
return group;
```

Voila! All the parse methods and checks that you need to write is encapsulated in that one ModelMixin "superclass".